# JTable y campos de distintas tablas de MySQL con DAO

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, patrones-de-diseño

Tengo una BD normalizada y por lo tanto en la estructura tengo la tabla "empleado" y la tabla "domicilio".
Donde la PK de domicilio es el "id_domicilio", que a su vez es FK de la tabla "empleado", por esto se relacionan.

Mi JTable tiene las columnas "LEGAJO","APELLIDO","NOMBRE","DOMICILIO","TELÉFONO".

Para llenar una fila con un registro y traer el domicilio completo(Calle y numero) hago lo siguiente:

```
"SELECT e.leg_empleado, e.ape_empleado, e.nom_empleado, CONCAT(d.nom_calle,' ',d.nro_calle) AS dom , e.tel_empleado " +
"FROM empleado AS e, domicilio AS d " +
"WHERE e.id_domicilio = d.id_domicilio " +
"AND e.nom_empleado LIKE '"+nombreCliente+'%'+"'"
```

Hasta ahí todo perfecto....

Para optimizar el sistema haciendo uso de patrones cree interfaces DAO y las clases que implementan sus métodos de CRUD.

Como ejemplo muestro el método getEmpleado para consultar por nombre.

```
@Override
    public EntidadEmpleado getEmpleado(String nombre) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Connection con = Conector.iniciarConexion();
        ResultSet rsGetEmpelado = null;
        EntidadEmpleado e = null;
                
                try {
                    if(!con.isClosed()){
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(getEmpleado);
                            ps.setString(1, nombre);
                            rsGetEmpelado = ps.executeQuery();
                            if (rsGetEmpelado.next()) {
                                e = new EntidadEmpleado(
                                        rsGetEmpelado.getInt("leg_empleado"),
                                        rsGetEmpelado.getInt("id_domicilio"),
                                        rsGetEmpelado.getString("ape_empleado"),
                                        rsGetEmpelado.getString("nom_empleado"),
                                        rsGetEmpelado.getString("tel_empleado"));
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }               
        return e; //Devuelve EntidadEmpleado
    }
```

El problema ahora es que en este método creo una instancia de EntidadEmpleado pasandole en el constructor los datos obtenidos de la BD. Pero para llenar la JTable me estaría faltando el domicilio real, ya que la clase de modelo EntidadEmpleado tiene id_domicilio (ejemplo: 1, 2 , 3, etc). y yo necesito Calle y Nro, tal como lo consigo sin usar DAO.
Disculpen si no se entendió el problema, se me dificulta explicarlo..

La duda es... Está bien que con el ResultSet cree una instancia de EntidadEmpleado o lo manejo simplemente para llenar lo que necesito en la JTable desde el ResultSet?

Quizás no esté bien normalizada la BD y no haga falta separar la tabla Domicilio y colocar como campos de la tabla Empleado Calle y Numero.

En caso de que no tenga otra solución, qué recomiendan?

Desde ya muchas gracias!
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguno le sirve, resolví el problema creando una nueva clase EntidadEmpleadoDAO con los atributos que necesito en la JTable y en lugar de instanciar y retornar un EntidadEmpleado, estoy instanciando y retornando EntidadEmpleadoDAO.
Usé la misma sentencia SQL para tomar los datos necesarios de ambas tablas y ahora mi tabla quedó con todo lo que necesito ver y mi BD sigue con FN3.

Saludos.